# How to load new chart (chartsjs) from api call with jquery?

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I'm using Perl Dancer to at the server. Trying to create some charts. The data I've created is all okay. Creating a page with a chart works. However, when trying to load a chart from data received from the server via an api-call I get confused. jQuery is not my expertise.

Currently I'm able to see the json-data received. Guess I'm almost there but can't find out how to get the data to the chart-settings.

Code I have this far.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<H1>Make a choice</H1>

<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        $('#choice').click(function(){
            var singleValue = $( "#single").val();
            console.log("Clicked and Sending " + singleValue);
            $.post( "/fruits-api", {
                single: $('#single').val(),
                }, function( data ) {
                console.log( "Response reveived:", data );
                createMyChart(); // <--- ? how to get the chart loaded?
            });
        })
    });
</script>


<!-- Select Box -->
<button id="choice">Go!</button>

<select id="single">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Pineapples">Pineapples</option>
    <option value="Pears">Pears</option>
    <option value="Melons">Melons</option>
</select>


<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>


<script>
var settings = {
    url: "/pear-api",
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
}

function createMyChart() {
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response){

    var l = [];
    for(var i in response) {
        l.push(
        moment.utc(response[i].datum).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        );
    }
    console.log(l);
    var z = [];
    for(var i in response) {
        z.push({
        t:moment.utc(response[i].datum).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        y:response[i].totaal
        });
    }
    console.log(z);

    // Position of the chart
    var timeFormat = moment('YYYY-MM-DD')
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, 
    {
        type: 'line',
        options: 
        {
            responsive: true,
            scales: 
            {
                xAxes: 
                [{ 
                    display: true,
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {
                            'day': 'DD-MMM-YYYY'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        data: 
        {
            labels: l,
            datasets: 
            [{
                label: 'Quantity',
                fill: true,
                borderColor: 'blue',
                pointBorderColor: 'red',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'yellow',
                pointBorderWidth: 7,
                data:  z
            }],
        }
    });
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to remove/comment the initial 'var settings' and in the function call I forgot to add parameters:

```
createMyChart(data)
```

Also setting the header in the api call in Dancer is essential!

```
    header ('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
```